# react/typescript: Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type. After Using IProps interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I don't understand why I have this type of error

`Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Because I using iterface before to used props in constructor method.
Below I put whole react component when I have the problem

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { FetchPokemon } from '../../actions';

import * as React from 'react';
import { HeaderComponent } from './HeaderComponent';

import {IStoreState} from '../../types';

interface IProps {
  pokemon: object[];
  FetchPokemon: () => void;
}
interface IState {
  example: boolean
}

class HeaderContainer extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      example: false
    }

    this.FetchAction = this.FetchAction.bind(this);
  }

  public FetchAction = () => {
    this.props.FetchPokemon()
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log(this.props)}
        <HeaderComponent fetchAction={this.FetchAction}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IStoreState) => ({
  pokemon: state.fetchPokemon
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {FetchPokemon})(HeaderContainer) as any;
```

Do anyone have some idea ?

Comment: Have you tried `constructor(props: IProps) { super(props as any); }`?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sorry for that, but I now in TypeScript. The solution works

Comment: Could I ask you for create ansewer because now I can't close ansewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strict nature of TypeScript requires you to be clear about certain types and object, depending on your transpiler configuration. When it comes to React and TypeScript it is suggested to write the constructor as follows:

```typescript
class Component extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    public constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props as any);
    }
}
```